# JavaFX Draw a Single Axis

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

How can I draw a single Axis to a pane?

It gives me a runtime exception if I naively try `addAll(axis)`

I am browsing through the XYChart source for answers on how it draws axis.

EDIT:

Source

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestSingleAxis extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        StackPane root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren().addAll(new NumberAxis(1, 20, 1));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1300, 800, Color.WHITESMOKE);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

}
```

Results

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:548)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:48)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javafx.scene.chart.Axis.layoutChildren(Axis.java:744)
    at javafx.scene.chart.ValueAxis.layoutChildren(ValueAxis.java:359)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1014)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.layout(Parent.java:1022)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.layoutDirtyRoots(Scene.java:537)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.doLayoutPass(Scene.java:508)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.preferredSize(Scene.java:1467)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_preferredSize(Scene.java:1494)
    at javafx.stage.Window$10.invalidated(Window.java:720)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:106)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:140)
    at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Window.java:783)
    at javafx.stage.Window.show(Window.java:798)
    at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Stage.java:242)
    at guifx.TestSingleAxis.start(TestSingleAxis.java:32)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:491)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:223)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:220)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:220)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What is the exception? Exploring the code - is the right way! =)

Comment: Cleaned it up nice and simple, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observing some version of code, near the line 744 I see:

```
    if (getSide().equals(Side.LEFT)) {
```

And this code says me :

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    System.out.println(new NumberAxis(1, 2, 3).getSide());
}

>>null
```

Seems, you need to specify the side anyway..

Does it help?

Comment: Good observation, code runs now.  But try setting it to Side.BOTTOM it draws on top, and for Side.TOP draws on bottom.  Is there something else wrong here?

Comment: According to javadoc : ObjectProperty<Side> side
The side of the plot which this axis is being drawn on

If it is not so - file an issue to javafx-jira.